# Filter custom taxonomy table

Tags: taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I am trying to make a limited admin panel for some users.

I would like to customize the taxonomy menu so that there is only one term visible when a user has a specific capability, but also allow him to add/remove children from that term (hierachically).

Is there a filter or an action to do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15845723/1287812).

Comment: Actually, I am talking about having this to edit-tags.php of my custom taxonomy, on the screen that you can add and edit taxonomies.

Comment: Can you update the Question and add more details to it? Some experiment on your part with the code in the previous link would be welcome too.

Comment: I don't have anything, for now, let's say that I want to manipulate the query of the wp_list_table on taxonomy list page, so that it will show only a specific term and its children, and allow to add/delete only its children.